# How to resize all forms to specific resolution including controls

Tags: vb6, resolution

I am able to resize my current main form by doing this:

```
Form1.Hight = Screen.TwipsPerPixelY * 600
Form1.Width = Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 800
```

The issue is my program contains more forms that open up. I want them all to resize to this resolution, including the controls.

How can I do this?

Comment: start here: [Resizing Controls on Form](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?376702-Classic-VB-Resizing-Controls-on-Form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that loops through all the controls in your project and create global variables that will be accessed in that function.

Use this function when you want to resize